# how can one construct a complete orthogonal sequence in $\ell^2$?

Tags: functional-analysis

For instance, the set/sequence defined by $\{e_1 = (1, 0, 0, ...), e_2 = (0, 1, 0, ...), e_3 = (0, 0, 1, 0, ...), ..., (0, ..., 0, 1, 0, ...), ...\}$

is orthogonal, since the inner product of any pair of these is zero, but it is not complete.

How can we construct one that is complete?

I know that an orthogonal sequence $\{x_n\}$ in $X$ is complete if every $x \in X$ can be expressed in the following way:

$$x = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}<x, x_k>x_k$$
But how will that help me construct a complete orthogonal set/sequence in $\ell^2$?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you say that $\{e_n\}$ isn't complete?

Comment: $\{e_n\}_n $ is complete.